# How to check if the WaitHandle was set?

Tags: c#, waithandle

I have a [WaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx) and I would like to know how to check if the WaitHandle has already been set or not.

**Note:** I can add a bool variable and whenever Set() method is used set the variable to true, but this behaviour must be built in WaitHandle somewhere.

Thanks for help!

Comment: My answer was only seconds before SwDevMan's which is much clearer and includes the documentation quote, so I'm deleting it.  However, I still wonder "Are you dealing with an auto-reset event that might already have been reset, or that the test code must not reset?"

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try [WaitHandle.WaitOne(0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907.aspx)

> If millisecondsTimeout is zero, the method does not block. It tests the state of the wait handle and returns immediately.

Comment: +1 Good clear answer. Nice and simple, though I would suggest changing "Try" to "Use". As it stands, you seem unsure of your answer.

Comment: The only issue is that for some WaitHandles (auto-reset event, semaphore), the ready state will actually be reset by waiting on it.

Comment: @Vivin joy - `millisecondsTimeout` is the parameter name to the `WaitOne` call, please see the link.  Its a quote taken from the Remarks section

Comment: @MartinVseticka Don't be ashamed! I came here with the same question. The answer is perhaps guessable, but by no means self-evident.

Comment: It doesn't just check if the wait handle is AutoResetEvent! It actually changes its state to true.

Answer (score 7):

```
const int DoNotWait = 0;
                          
ManualResetEvent waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);                   

Console.WriteLine("Is set:{0}", waitHandle.WaitOne(DoNotWait));
         
waitHandle.Set(); 

Console.WriteLine("Is set:{0}", waitHandle.WaitOne(DoNotWait));
```

Output:

> Is set:False
>
> Is set:True

Comment: Why use a keyword for the variable? It's unnecessary and makes your answer harder to read.

Comment: @Jeff Sure, it's just a hard thing to name for some sample code, and I've been writing a lot of code today.

Comment: @chibacity: it's easy to write something other than event. `waitHandle`, `resetEvent`, `mre`, `myEvent`. The list is endless and it would make your example better.

Comment: @Jeff You have no idea of my state of mental exhaustion at the moment - but I will comply! :)

Comment: @chibacity: I can sympathise but if a job's worth doing, it's worth doing well. +1

Comment: @Jeff Cheers for the kick up the bum, you are quite right. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the `Wait...` methods on [`WaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f7e54k1.aspx) that takes a timeout value, such as [`WaitOne`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907.aspx), and pass a timeout of 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout, bool exitContext)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy257t0.aspx) method and pass in 0 for the timespan. It will return right away.

```
bool isSet = yourWaitHandle.WaitOne(0, true);
```

Comment: Why should they use the one that takes an `exitContext` value? Considering that there are alternatives which do not require this field, you should explain its necessity.

Comment: Online help for VS2005 only shows WaitOne(), WaitOne(int,bool), and WaitOne(TimeSpan,bool). So, it's likely they didn't find WaitOne(int)